# VS2017 C++ dependency graph tools

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

Want to know if there are any good tools / extension for VS2017 which generate c++ dependency graph.

Have tried cppdepend, though not much satisfied. There are some references which exists though not shown in the graph (could be because ref added but not used). The solution is having 150+ projs includes c#, c++, web, win, wpf, etc. Want to understnd C++ dependency better. I am not cpp developer so looking for a proper tool which can be trusted as I won't be able to confirm if graph generated is 100% correct Your experience will help. Thanks.

Comment: If you can contact the cppdepend support team to give them more details about the missing dependencies. they will try to help you to resolve this issue.

Comment: Not sure if support is available for trial version. In case support is available yet I can't share my source code to them. Only simple question would be if proj A is having reference added for Proj B in VS, then what would be the reason cppdepend doesn't show it still. And my interest is to explore more such tools other than cppdepend.

Comment: The support is also available for the trial version to improve the product. Just send an email to support@cppdepend.com, they will try to help you resolve your issue.